# Vanilla JavaScript - Object.keys(object).forEach display only the last item

Tags: javascript, object, foreach

I have a function that iterates through an object.

On the HTML it should display each key and value from the object within its own table row.

```
Object.keys(nutrients).forEach(function(key) {
    const nutrientsList = nutrients[key];

    nutritionTable.innerHTML = `<tr>
                                    <td>${[ nutrientsList.label ]}</td>
                                    <td>${[ nutrientsList.quantity ]} ${[ nutrientsList.unit ]}</td>
                                </tr>`
});
```

When console.log it shows as expected but on the HTML over rights all the previous elements and shows only the last one.

[DEMO](https://jsbin.com/gasuvep/1/edit?html,js,output)

How can I improve the code and get the right result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're replacing the whole HTML content on each iteration. I assume you want to append each time. To do this use [`.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) instead.

```
Object.keys(nutrients).forEach(function(key) {
    const nutrientsList = nutrients[key];

    nutritionTable.insertAdjacentHTML(
        "beforeend",
        `<tr>
             <td>${[ nutrientsList.label ]}</td>
             <td>${[ nutrientsList.quantity ]} ${[ nutrientsList.unit ]}</td>
        </tr>`);
});
```

This is the preferred way of appending new content from existing HTML since any form of `.innerHTML` assignment, including `+=`, will destroy the existing DOM before adding any new content. This can produce undesirable side-effects.

---

As an aside, since you're using ECMAScript 2015 features, you may want to consider a `for-of` loop.

```
for (const nutrientsList of Object.values(nutrients)) {
    nutritionTable.insertAdjacentHTML(
        "beforeend",
        `<tr>
             <td>${[ nutrientsList.label ]}</td>
             <td>${[ nutrientsList.quantity ]} ${[ nutrientsList.unit ]}</td>
        </tr>`);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- `x = y` : **overrides** the value of `x` by `y`.
- `x += y` (or `x = x+y`) : **appends** `y` value to the current value of `x`.

Then :

```
 nutritionTable.innerHTML += `<tr>....` // append
```

And not

```
 nutritionTable.innerHTML = `<tr>....` // override
```

Answer (score 0):

In every iteration you change the value of the `innerHTML` of the nutritionTable (so you actually override that value in each iteration in the loop, and the final value is the value of the final iteration in your loop).

Instead - you can use `+=` to append that value:

```
Object.keys(nutrients).forEach(function(key) {
    const nutrientsList = nutrients[key];

    nutritionTable.innerHTML += `<tr>
                                    <td>${[ nutrientsList.label ]}</td>
                                    <td>${[ nutrientsList.quantity ]} ${[ nutrientsList.unit ]}</td>
                                </tr>`
});
```